# Tomcat HTTP Base Authentification and JAX-WS: Client Generation fails

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws, basic-authentication

I'm trying to send a request to a `JAX-WS` webservice which is secured by HTTP Base Authentification. The `web.xml` file of the service contains the following statements:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>secured services</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/services/PortalWebservice/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>onlineadapter</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint> 
  <security-role>
    <role-name>onlineadapter</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <login-config>   
   <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>   
   <realm-name>onlineadapter</realm-name>   
  </login-config>
```

My tomcat-user.xml contains this:

```
<role rolename="onlineadapter"/>
<user username="onlineadapter" password="onlineadapter" roles="onlineadapter"/>
```

Then i try to create a Client during runtime like this:

```
int timeOut = 60000;
IPortaladapterWebservice service = new PortaladapterWebservice(new URL("http://localhost:8080/OnlineAdapter/services/PortaladapterWebservice")).getPortaladapterWebservicePort();
((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, timeOut);
if (aUser != null && !aUser.equals("") && aPassword != null && !aPassword.equals(""))
{
    ((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "onlineadapter");
    ((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "onlineadapter");
}
```

Problem: Whenever i call `getPortaladapterWebservicePort` i get the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/OnlineAdapter/services/PortaladapterWebservice
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/OnlineAdapter/services/PortaladapterWebservice?wsdl
```

I guess the Statuscode 401 is related to my Client not beeing authorized for requests. So why is the error coming before i am even able to set user and password? How else is this done in a `JAX-WS` Client?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a way to get it work by using an `Authenticator`, which has to be set before the Port is queried:

```
    if (aUser != null && !aUser.equals("") && aPassword != null && !aPassword.equals(""))
    {
        Authenticator.setDefault(getDefaultAuthenticator(aUser, aPassword));
    }

    service = new PortaladapterWebservice(new URL(mUrl)).getPortaladapterWebservicePort();
    ((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 60000);
```

where the getDefaultAuthenticator() Method is defined as:

```
private Authenticator getDefaultAuthenticator (String aUser, String aPassword)
    {
        return new Authenticator() 
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(aUser, aPassword.toCharArray());
            }
        };
    }
```